# Failed to enumerate processes: unable to connect to remote frida-server: closed

Tags: android, frida

After initialize frida-server (16.0.0) on my device, I try to connect from my PC by using frida-ps -U and I get the error: *Failed to enumerate processes: unable to connect to remote frida-server: closed*.

The frida version that I have installed on my PC is 16.0.0 and the frida-tools version is 12.0.0

Thanks!

[Initializing frida-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mRRw.png)

[Error given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDdEl.png)

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I just installed the Magisk module "MagiskFrida". https://github.com/ViRb3/magisk-frida

Comment: Broke my magisk, on reboot, to delete this:'adb wait-for-device shell magisk --remove-modules'